# How to stub a promisified method using Sinon.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

Given the following code:
(Note that access was promisified)

```
const fs = require('fs')
const util = require('util')
const access = util.promisify(fs.access)

const custom = () => {
  return access('myfile', fs.constants.R_OK)
    .then(() => {
      return true
    }).catch(err => {
      if (err.code !== 'ENOENT') throw err
      return false
    }).then(fileExists => {
      return `File exists: ${fileExists}`
    })
}

module.exports = custom
```

My unit test is not working because the real `access` method is being called instead of the stubbed one:

```
const chai = require('chai')
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised')
const custom = require('./custom')
const fs = require('fs')
const sinon = require('sinon')

chai.use(chaiAsPromised)
const expect = chai.expect

describe('custom', () => {
  let sandbox = sinon.createSandbox()

  afterEach(function () {
    sandbox.restore()
  })

  it('should return file exists true', () => {
    sandbox.stub(fs, 'access').yields(null)
    return expect(custom()).to.eventually.equal('File exists: true')
  })

  it('should return file exists false', () => {
    const error = new Error('No such file or directory')
    error.code = 'ENOENT'
    sandbox.stub(fs, 'access').yields(error)
    return expect(custom()).to.eventually.equal('File exists: false')
  })
})
```

How to make the test works, givem `access` is promisified in the `custom.js` file?

References:

- [Node.JS fs.access method](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/fs.html)
- [sinon package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon)
- [chai package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai)
- [chai-as-promised package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-as-promised)

Comment: It seems like there is some confusion here: by trying to test the Promisified fs.stat's callback, you're basically trying to make sure that Bluebird's Promisify is working as expected. No need to do that, the Bluebird developers already did it.
Your existing/non-existing file test has also been done by the node.js folks, so no need to test that either.
Possibly you want to disclose what/why you're trying to test...

Comment: Thanks for your response, I updated the question with part of the logic that I'm trying to test.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** *Question has been updated. Answer to original question at the bottom*

What you are looking for is [Proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire).
The problem is that `custom.js` requires its own `fs`, and you are stubbing the `fs` in your test file. `Proxyquire` will require a file, and replace any files/functions you want, which that file requires.

In your example, it would go something like this.
(run it with `mocha <test file path>`)

**test file:**

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
const expect = chai.expect;

describe('custom', () => {
    let custom;

    const stubs = {
        fs: {
            accessAsync: () => {
                // Since you mentioned that fs was promisified, we will
                // make this a promise as well.
                return Promise.resolve();
            }
        },
        bluebird: {
            // Stop bluebird from promisifying, since we handle it above.
            promisifyAll: (req => req),
        }
    };

    before(async function () {
        custom = proxyquire('./custom', stubs);
    });

    it('should return file exists true', () => {
        return expect(custom()).to.eventually.equal('File exists: true');
    });
});
```

**custom.js**

```
'use strict';

const bluebird = require('bluebird');
const fs = bluebird.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

module.exports = async function() {
    let exists = true;
    await fs.accessAsync('nonimportant.path', fs.constants.F_OK)
        .catch( () => { exists = false; });
    return `File exists: ${exists}`;
};
```

**Original answer**

No need to use bluebird in this case, Sinon can handle that.

You need to use the [sinon.stub()](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.7/stubs/) function. It can be done like this:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const fs = require('fs');

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
const expect = chai.expect;

describe('fs.stat', function(){
    before(function() {
        sinon.stub(fs, 'stat').resolves('Your desired value');
    });

    it('should should be called', function(done){
        expect(fs.stat('./some.file'))
            .to.eventually.equal('Your desired value')
            .notify(done);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I said, the fs.stat was promisified, so I need an example that show how to stub that. In your example you are showing fs.stat will be used in the original version: with a callback not a promise.

Comment: Hey Enslev. Really nice finding! Thank you very much. Looks like proxyquire is the solution. I'm trying to run your unit test, but I'm getting the classical time out error of 2s from chai.
"Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves."
Should work without calling done, as you are returning the promise to the Describe method and chai-as-promised is being used.
Did your example passed when you run in your environment?

Comment: No sorry. I didn't run that test. It was more of a proof of concept, to point you in the right direction. For completeness sake, I will update with a working example test.

Comment: Sorry for the wait, got caught up in work. I fixed the test to actually be working, and included the `custom.js` file i have been using for the test. Please remember to mark as accepted, if the answer helped you :)

Comment: Hi Enslev. Thanks again for your reply.
I was able to make it works using promisifyAll of bluebird as well. This works as a *new* accessAsync method is created. But I'd like to not promisify a entire package only to use a specific promisified method. Because of this I promisified *only* the access method.
I'd like to not give up and try to find a solution, as I have many other user cases for spot promisified methods ...
Thank you very much for your effort. I can accept your answer as the correct one, but I still have this open question to investigate :-(

Comment: I don't see how promisifying only one, instead of every function, changes the test. This should still work.
If not, can you update with the method you are using to promisify?